# why does "." space not produce a list of all methods. in jupyter

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, code-completion

I'm trying to create a class that has multiple functions, such that when I type "." and hit the space button in jupyter, a list of all the methods would pop up.

example:

```
class classname:
    def func1(x,y):
        return(x+y)
    def func2(x,y):
        return(x+y)
```

what i'm expecting is that after I import the file and do:

`classname.`
and hit the space bar, func1 and func2 would appear in a dropdown.

right now, nothing is happening.

Comment: If those are supposed to be static methods, consider using the `@staticmethod` annotation. Also consider whether putting the functions in a class is necessary at all.

Comment: I'm fairly new to using classes and oop in general, so I may not be understanding the response fully.  For my situation,  I'm imagining a classname that has a list of functions, so the user who has this file can just "." tab to see what all is available.

Answer (score 0):

It might take some time before the drop down with functions could appear. I've experienced it myself when the notebook already has tons of content in it.

I replicated your example in a fresh notebook and it took about a little more than a second for the drop down to appear.

[image]

The notebook server I'm running is `6.0.2` with Python version `3.7.5`. Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks. looks like it works for me now.  how do we get rid of the "nro"?  when I'm using other packages like scikit-learn, is this similar to how methods are done?  I'm wanting to have similar type of idea for my object, but not sure if there is a 'proper' way to do it.